# custom autoload vs default

Tags: php, autoload

which autoload method is faster?

```
    private $_directoriesToLook = array("framework/", "models/", "controllers/");
```

Custom autoloader:

```
    private function customAutoloader($class_name)
    {
        if(class_exists($class_name))
            return true;

        foreach($this->_directoriesToLook as $directory)
        {
            $files = scandir($directory);

            if(in_array($class_name.".php", $files))
            {
                require_once($directory.$class_name.".php");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    spl_autoload_register(array($this, "customAutoloader"));
```

Default autoloader:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $this->_directoriesToLook));
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");  
spl_autoload_register();
```

Although I've read that default one must be faster, according to my tests the custom method wins.
The drawback of default method is that the classes must be all lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says the default auto loader will be faster. If you only search three directories with your custom auto loader and a all your directories in `get_include_path()`, your custom auto loader might be faster. However that is not a fair comparison.

Comment: The problem with default method is that it doesn't allow to use camel case class/file names.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the slight performance gain from the default auto loader. Just do your custom auto loader with camel case support. Readable code is more important than gaining some ms of execution time.